# Bill Splitter Calculator Android App Program Logic

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an Android app to help to calculate split the bill if let's say you're eating out in a party of 2 people or more.

You're supposed to enter the subtotal of the bill, enter the number of people in the party, enter applicable discount if any, there are 2 checkboxes for 7% tax, and 10% service charges if it hasn't been included in the bill yet. Finally you just need to click on the "calculate button" for the app to calculate how much each person has to pay.

The program takes the subtotal amount when user inputs it,
calculate the additional discount if there's any, take the amount after discount,
calculate the additional 7% GST tax if the checkbox is checked, or doesn't do anything if it's unchecked
calculate the additional 10% tips if the checkbox is checked, or doesn't do anything if it's unchecked.

I am unsure of my implementation of the program's logic, will also appreciate if someone can check on it and give feedback. The Logic of the app is supposed to be:

Here's the code that I wrote:

```
    gst = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbCheck1);
    gst.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() { 
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (gst.isChecked()) {
                result = result + (0.07 * result);
            } else {
                result = result;
            }
        }
    });


    tips = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbCheck2);
    tips.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (tips.isChecked()) {
                result = result + (0.1 * result);
            } else {
                result = result;
            }
        }
    });  

    //Initialize EditTexts
    String amount = enterAmount.getText().toString();
    double subtotal = Double.valueOf(amount).doubleValue();

    String diners = numberDiners.getText().toString();
    int people = Integer.parseInt(diners);

    String disc = enterDiscount.getText().toString();
    int discount = Integer.parseInt(disc);
    double discounted = discount / 100;

    result = (1 - discounted) * (subtotal / people);
```

Thank you in advance for all of your kind feedbacks.

Comment: umm - why hardcode the tax?  or any gratuity or service charge? these things vary.

Comment: it looks like the result will keep increasing if the user keeps toggling the gst checkbox

Comment: is there a suggestion on how should I approach this so that it will not keep increasing when the user keeps toggling the checkboxes?

The reason to hardcode it is that because in the country I live in, the tax and service charge are fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use logic as you would a calulator? Enter the total bill, enter the number of people, enter tax and enter tip.

```
1) total = total * (1+tax)
2) total = total * (1+tip)
3) totalPerPerson = total / numPeeps
```

Truthfully, I'm not entirly sure what is giving you so much trouble.

Edit 1: As a hind thought, something for you to consider, when my friends and I go out, we pay for only what we got; we don't split the tab evenly. Maybe you could consider adding that kind of functionality?

Edit 2: To address your comment, you are always setting result to at least result. You need to set it back to application default when the check box is unchecked. Maybe `if (!isChecked) result = 1;`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and additional functionality ... I'll try it out. Thanks :)